# PHP - MySQL display highest ID number

Tags: php, mysql

What SQL query would I use to display the newest entry?
Details:

id is the primary field. I have other fields but that are not related to when they were added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * from yourTable ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Another (better) way would be to have a "date_added" column (`date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) so you could order by that column descending instead. Dates are more reliable than ID-assignment.

Comment: This is very likely to be the fastest of all the suggestions at this point :)

Comment: Yeah! It is pretty simple too.

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
use the MAX() function
```

Since you didn't give any details about your table it is hard to answer

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what your looking for but I use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) after inserting a new row

Answer (score 1):

The auto incremented ID columns are not always the latest records inserted, I've remember really painful experience with this behavior. Conditions where specific, it was mysql 4.1.x at the time and there was almost 1 million records, where 1 out of 3 deleted everiday, and others re inserted in the next 24hours. It made a huge mess when I realize ordering them via ID was not ordering them by age....

Since then, I use a specific column for doing age related sorts, and populating these fields with `date = NOW()` at each row insert. 
Of course it will work to found the latest record as you want, doing an `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1`on your query

Comment: ID works fine for me, I clear the table every night. But this is a very good point.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Primary_Key_Field FROM table ORDER BY Primary_Key_Field DESC LIMIT 1`

Replace `Primary_Key_Field` and `table` obviously :)